# Laplace transformation-exponential

Tags: laplace-transform

I need to get the Inverse Laplace Transform in the form of following function:

$$e^{-\alpha \sqrt{p^2+\beta^2}}$$

α and β being some parameters which α is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathcal{L}_{\alpha }^{-1}\left[\exp \left(-\alpha  \sqrt{p^2+\beta ^2}\right)\right](t)=\delta (t-\alpha )-\frac{\alpha  \beta  \ H (t-\alpha ) J_1\left(\sqrt{t^2-\alpha ^2} \beta \right)}{\sqrt{t^2-\alpha ^2}}$$

where $J_1(t)$ is  [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

where $\ H (t-\alpha )$ is  Heaviside theta function.

where $\delta (t-\alpha )$ is  Dirac delta function.

From [Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420066528). Table A.5.1 example 191.

Comment: thank you for the answer and introducing the useful reference.

Comment: @m.sakha.This is also a very good book for Inverse Laplace transforms :http://www.worldcat.org/title/integrals-and-series-volume-5-inverse-laplace-transforms/oclc/489706146

Comment: The delta function term is missing. For large $p$ on the line $\operatorname {Re} p = \gamma > 0$, $F(p)$ is close to $e^{-\alpha p}$, the integral of which diverges:
$$\mathcal L^{-1} \!\left[ \exp\left (
  -\alpha \sqrt {p^2 + \beta^2}\right) \right] =
- \frac {\alpha \beta J_1 \left( \beta \sqrt {t^2 - \alpha^2} \right)}
 {\sqrt {t^2 - \alpha^2}} H(t - \alpha) + \delta(t - \alpha).$$

Comment: @Maxim. Thanks. :)